# npm stuck in idealTree:laravel_demo: sill idealTree buildDeps

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

In my Laravel project, there is no package-lock.json nor node_modules folder to remove. I have already tried setting the registry. I also reinstalled the NodeJS. None of them are working. I am not connected to a VPN either. I am already waiting for about 1 hour and my internet connection is 50mbps. Is there something else I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by 1) reinstalling both composer and nodejs 2) then rebooting my computer. This solution might be an addition to the solutions here in StackOverflow.